# lemmatize words in nest list

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, lemmatization

How do I lemmatize words in the nested list in a single line? I tried few things, I am getting close but I think I may be getting syntax wrong? How do I fix it?

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer 
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
word_list = [['test','exams','projects'],['math','exam','things']]
word_list # type list

Try #1: Does the lemmatization but in different format
for word in word_list:
    for e in word: 
        print(lemmatizer.lemmatize(e)) # not the result I need for 

Try #2: Looking for similar approach in one line to solve the problem. Not giving correct results. 
[[word for word in lemmatizer.lemmatize(str(doc))] for doc in word_list]

Output needed: 

[['test','exam','project'],['math','exam','thing']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a for loop solution for my question above. I couldn't get this into a single line, but it is working for now. If any one is looking for solution:

```
word_list_lemma = []
for ls in word_list:
    word_lem = []
    for word in ls:
        word_lem.append(lemmatizer.lemmatize(word))
    word_list_lemma.append(word_lem)
```